# How to write a regex to match Arabic, English, numerical and spacing characters?

Tags: php, regex

Using regular expressions in PHP, how can I make the user input Arabic, English, digits, _, -, or a space.

For example, the user can input the following strings:

- 10-abc
- 10-من
- 10-abcمن
- _abcمن-10

Answer (score 5):

To check for Arabic characters you can use

```
\p{InArabic}
```

[This](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script) page might help you on your way.

Comment: /p{InArabic}=>"unknown property name after \P or \p"  but /p{Arabic} works. Test version php 5.3, PCRE Library Version => 7.9 2009-04-11

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'/^([a-zA-Z0-9]|[\p{Arabic}]|[_])*$/u'
```